# stuck on the first step of ambari 2.7.3 install wizard

Tags: ambari

I have installed the Hortonworks sandbox HDP 2.6.5 (docker install).
After having many issues with Ambari "HeartBeat lost" I decided to upgrade Ambari to the latest version, so I cleanly uninstall ambari and then install 2.7.3 following the instructions from:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.3

After a long process I managed to complete the installation and start both services successfully: "ambari-server" and "ambari-agent"

Now I am stuck on the install wizard in the fisrt step without getting any error 
or any progress. That is, after hitting "Next" it never gets to step 2. (see picture)
[screenshot showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDw4k.png)
Things done so far to try to work this around:

- restarting services (several times)
- ambari-server upgrade (once more)
- trying with chrome and IE
- looking at the log files of ambari-server and ambari-agent

...but without success.
Has anybody come across the same issue?
Any clues?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just built and tried today. Same issue here. Nothing appear in the log. Just the pending icon next to the Next button.

Comment: well, if UI doesn't going further, then check for requests error in chrome F12 -> network. Most likely you could find XHR error

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and I have activated the stack as shown below:

```
sudo sed -i 's|<active>false</active>|<active>true</active>|g' /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.6/metainfo.xml
sudo sed -i 's|<active>false</active>|<active>true</active>|g' /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.4/metainfo.xml

cat /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.6/metainfo.xml
cat /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.4/metainfo.xml
```

then I restarted the ambari-server and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you have broken stacks for **HDP**. make sure you fresh build *ambari 2.7.3* from source

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.3
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Ambari+Development

1. copy folder and contents inside HDP stacks

   ```
   /root/ambari-release-2.7.3/ambari-server/src/main/resources/stacks/HDP
   ```

   `ambari-release-2.7.3` is folder result build from source
2. paste to broken ambari-server

   ```
   /var/lib/ambari-server/src/main/resources/stacks/
   ```
3. restart ambari server